# Bracket CSS Selector

Tags: css

Looking around for responsive web design and I came up with a piece of code which also exists in the Bootstrap framework.

Can someone please explain what the actual code does

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  [class*='col-'] {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Could not find the selector in [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) site which has a lot of selectors as examples

Comment: The page you linked has that rule, explained under 12).

Comment: Yes you are correct but what actually confused me there was no tag/element before the rule so I was wondering what is going on.

Comment: The page is not very precise, and 12) actually combines 5) with an attribute selector. You can use arbitrary combinations of the CSS selectors existing. Example: `td#id.class[type*=foo]:not(:invalid):nth-child(2n+1):hover::before`.

Answer (score 3):

```
[class*='col-']
```

is the so-called [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). The basic form is e.g. this:

```
[type='checkbox']
```

which would select all elements on a page that have an attribute `type` that equals `checkbox`.

The basic form can be modified using certain prefix characters:

```
[class*='col-']
```

matches all elements which have a class in their classlist whose name **contains** (`*=`) `col-`.

The same exists for **starts with**:

```
[class^='col-']
```

and for **ends with**:

```
[class$='col-']
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Combined with the media query, what that full rule does is make any container element that is defined as a Bootstrap column have the full width (and no longer be a column) instead (which is usually what you want on mobile devices like smartphones).

Answer (score 2):

This CSS means: For screen only, for a viewport maximum width of `768px` and below, for all elements with a class containing `col-`; set their width to `100%`.

Answer (score 2):

This complex selector in `css` but it is simple indeed.
Infact this is so usefull.

---

In following example there are four **divs** and there is `CSS` selector which checking if there is any of the `divs` having **test** in their class, then it selects them and apply properties on them.

```css
div[class*="test"] {
  background: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_test">The first div.</div>
<div class="second">The second div.</div>
<div class="test">The third div.</div>
<p class="test">This is some text.</p>
```